# getwalletinfo.hdseedid security

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

Command help getwalletinfo tells:

> "hdseedid": "hex", (string, optional) the Hash160 of the HD seed (only present when HD is enabled)

I understand that sharing this number will result in an immediate loss of funds, because this looks like should enable recreating the whole HD tree. Am I wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that sharing this number will result in an immediate loss of funds, because this looks like should enable recreating the whole HD tree. Am I wrong and why?

You're wrong. It is the hash of the seed, not the seed itself.